# Creating a Bluetooth COM Port on Windows Programmatically

Tags: windows, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have developed a Qt application that communicates with a specific bluetooth device. The application works on linux, android and mac flawlessly, but the qbluetooth api is not supported on windows. I have selected the serial api as a workaround, and have successfully done the task using a virtual COM port on the bluetooth device. The problem is that I don't want the end-user to create the COM port, and want to create it in setup time programmatically. I have done an extensive search, but have found no clue on it. Can anyone give me a hint on it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906454/accessing-bluetooth-virtual-com-port-on-windows-without-manual-pairing

Comment: thanks, but i had seen that link before. it is almost irrelevant. the final "close to answer" thing in that post is using a third party .net library, which doesn't handle serial over bluetooth very well. although the developer claims that he doesn't "like" serial over bluetooth, the real shortcoming of the 32feet library is that it cant tell you that name of the serial port! you can register a serial port over a bluetooth socket, but you must then find a magical way to guess it, like iterating over all the ports which is not elegant at all.